# Template rest one day from the date

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

In my `view.py` I obtain a date from my `MSSQL database` in this format `2018-12-06 00:00:00.000` so I pass that value as context like `datedb` and in my html page I render it like this `{{datedb|date:"c"}}` but it shows the date with one day less like this:

> 2018-12-05T18:00:00-06:00

Is the 06 not the 05 day.

**why is this happening? how can I show the right date?**

Comment: It shows the correct time, but with timezone -6:00, and your database (likely) stores it with UTC, probably use enabled `USE_TZ` in the settings?

Comment: yes I use `USE_TZ = True` in my setting

Comment: I just change it to `False` and works, thank you

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but now if I use `USE_TZ = False` gives error every part I use `timezone` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solve the problem was chage to `USE_TZ = False` has Willem said in the comments, but that gives another error so I found the way to do it just adding in the template this `{% load tz %}` and using the flter `|utc` on the date variables like `datedb|utc|date:'Y-m-d'`.